# Apply different conditional formatting to different rows

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

I typically use pandas to produce nice looking tabulated output in a workbook

How to apply different conditional formatting per row to highlight the cells that fail. Ie for the R1 row, values > 3,  R2 row values <5 etc...

or say... for each column, which R2 < R1

```
R1 = [1,10,3]
R2 = [4,5,6]
E_Rfsw = [7,8,9]

data = [R1, R2,E_Rfsw]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                columns=[V for V in design.Vout],
                index=['FB R1 (kΩ)', 'FB R2 (kΩ)','Fsw resistor (kΩ)'],
                )
display(df.round(4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need custom function with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
def highlight_row(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #filter index by R1, R2
    m1 = x.index.str.contains('R1')
    m2 = x.index.str.contains('R2')
    #compare filtered rows by conditions and add Falses for all rows
    mask = (x[m1] > 3).append((x[m2] > 5)).reindex(x.index, fill_value=False)
    #set values by mask
    df1 = df1.mask(mask, c1)
    return df1
df.style.apply(highlight_row, axis=None)
```

Sample data - only removed columns parameter, because `design.Vout` is not specified:

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks, this does what I require, especially as there is say 20rows and some relate to others and some to a threshold. Let me try in a bit but I think this is it. I tried to get my head around the styler but I just didn't quite get it